# Calling multiple webservices with different certificate types in a multithreaded environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, certificate

**My problem:**

I have a webapp (.NET 4.5.1) doing multiple calls to external webservices.
Some of the services only communicates over SSL and other over TSL only.

I know that, for some reason, ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol can be set statically globaly for the appdomin (Why its global I have no idea), but since multiple calls can occure at the same time to different external services in different threads - I can't just change the SecurityProtcol for the appdomain for each service call.

**Question:**

How should I handle this in a multithreaded web app environment?
Should I make service calls spawn in different appdomains where I can set SecurityProtocol? And if so - how should I do that?

Comment: Will a custom channel be created and consumed inside the multi-threaded environment suit your use case.

Comment: If it will solve the threading problem that I descriped to okarpov bellow - then yes of course.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and found this solution that worked for me.

I just use `ServicePointManager` to handle connection certificates

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);

private bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object Sender, X509Certificate Certificate, X509Chain Chain, SslPolicyErrors PolicyErrors)
        {
            ...
        }
```

To handle with with different requests I had a dictionary mapping server urls to a task. Each task runs asynchronously meaning that I don't have to handle with threads directly and inside each one I finally used System.Net objects. Namely, `HttpWebRequest`, `FtpWebRequest` and `SmtpWebRequest`.
Each one of them has a property to enable/disable SSL connection but they all worked with the same method to validate certificates.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft:

> public static SecurityProtocolType SecurityProtocol { get; set; }
>
> This property selects the version of the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) or Transport Layer Security 
>   (TLS) protocol to use for new connections that use the Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTPS) > scheme only; existing connections are not changed.

Please, pay attention about: "to use for new connections ... existing connections are not changed"

so, update this property just before opening a new connection

Comment: Well, as I wrote in my question I know about using the static property, however it doesn't work in a multithreaded environment since multiple threads can be adjusting that static during a service call is beeing created. It basically needs to be a threadsafe solution. The "existing connections are not changed." only applies to service calls allready created.

Comment: yes, you need lock in your case to be able to set the property and create a call and then release the lock

Comment: Well, that would need me to use the same lock on every service call wich effectivly would lock the webapplication for all users that needs to get service data during a single user service call. It's a solution, just not a very useful one.

Answer (score 0):

How many external services does your app use? Can't you create ServicePoints beforehand ( on app start) and just reuse them when needed?